# QProcess doesnt read input from separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qprocess

I am trying to use QProcess to read from a thread that continuously outputs something. I wrote these two programs to test. While QProcess can pick up the output of the main thread("Counting..."), there is no ouput picked up. When I changed the while loop to a for loop, there is an output, but only after the program has finished executing. Is there a way to  read a live ouput from a separate thread using QProcess?

Qt code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    process = new QProcess(this);
    connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readOutput()));
    //connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),this,SLOT(readOutput()));
    process->setArguments(args);
    process->setProgram("C:\\Users\\chten\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\QProcess\\test\\Debug\\test.exe");
    process->start();
    process->waitForStarted();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    process->close();
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::readOutput() {
    ui->input->append(process->readAllStandardOutput());
}
```

C++ code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void counting() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        i++;
        std::cout << i << "\n";
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{ 1 });
    }
}

int main(int  argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Counting..." << endl;
    boost::thread t{ counting };
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I am trying to use QProcess to read from a thread" - That doesn't make any sense. `QProcess` is for managing seperate *processes*, not *threads*.

Comment: From the symptoms I'd guess this might just be a buffering issue.  Try changing `"\n"` in your `counting` implementation to `std::endl` (as used in `main`).